# I want to share all of files in laravel framework named by t05 on github but it have a trouble .env file is not shared. I don't know why

Tags: php, laravel, github, server, environment

I want to share all of files in laravel framework named by t05 but it have a trouble .env file is not shared. I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy276.png)

Comment: In any case, you should not upload an .env file to GitHub because it contains sensitive information such as database passwords and other credentials. If you want to do so, remove .env from .gitignore.

Comment: thank you very much. I just fixed it by removing .env keyword from .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `.env` file isn't tracked by Git and it is a good practice to do that, because local `.env` may contain sensitive information about your app. The good approch is making your own `.env` file after cloning the repo by copying `.env.example` and configure is as you want. If you really want to track the `.env` file, just remove it from `.gitignore` file.

[Learn more about .gitignore](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/)